# Read matrix from txt file in Python (no numpy) using function

Tags: python, matrix

I am beginner and trying to Read a matrix from a text file and return it and use function read_matrix(pathname)
but all that I can find and build it and it does not work. Can you help me understand where I did wrong. Please no numpy

```
def read_matrix(pathname):
matrices=[]
m=[]
for line in file("matrix.txt",'r'):
   if line=="1 1\n": 
      if len(m)>0: matrices.append(m)
      m=[]
   else:
      m.append(line.strip().split(' '))
if len(m)>0: matrices.append(m)
return(m)
m = read_matrix('matrix.txt')
```

Comment: What have you try? How the text file is structure?

Comment: txt file includes 3 lines each with 3 numbers

Comment: Are you trying to read 1 matrix or several matrices? Your verbal description suggests 1 but your code seems to be trying to read multiple matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your file looks like this:

```
data.txt:

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

you can read it to a matrix (list of lists) as follow:

```
with open("data.txt") as fid:
    txt=fid.read()


matrix = [[int(val) for val in line.split()] for line in txt.split('\n') if line]
```

your code could work as follow, however there are some lines which could be written better:

```
def read_matrix(pathname):
    matrices = []
    m = []
    for line in open(pathname,'r'):
        if line=="1 1\n": 
            if len(m) > 0: 
                matrices.append(m)
                m=[]
        else:
            m.append(line.strip().split(' '))
    if len(m)>0: matrices.append(m)
    return(m)

m = read_matrix('data.txt')
```

Comment: I was able to read with file = open("matrix.txt",'r') but I want use function   def read_matrix(filename)

Comment: i have edited and added you code, however i do not know why you check lines like "  1 1"